# Pyspark explode array column into sublist with sliding window

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a rowin PySpark I would like to break into smaller rows given one of the values inside a column.

Given a df:

```
input_df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (2,[1,2,3,4,5],),
    ], ("id", "list"))

+---+------------+
| id|        list|
+---+------------+
|  2|[1, 2, 3, 4]|
+---+------------+
```

I would like to break each single row into multiple subsist with a fixed size sliding window. Resultant df would be like this:

```
output_df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (2, [0,0], 1), (2, [0,1], 2), (2, [1,2], 3), (2, [2,3], 4), (2, [3,4], 5),
    ], ("id", "past", "future"))

+---+------+------+
| id|  past|future|
+---+------+------+
|  2|[0, 0]|     1|
|  2|[0, 1]|     2|
|  2|[1, 2]|     3|
|  2|[2, 3]|     4|
|  2|[3, 4]|     5|
+---+------+------+
```

The logic on how to break the list to have a pointer looking at each element of the list, use the previous N elements (N=2 in this case) as past (fill with 0s if not enough elements) and use the current pointer element as future. Doing this on every element creates the dataframe.

I can not think on a way to do this with pyspark, I would do an iterative for loop per each row with a pandas dataframe. Is there a way to do this with pyspark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to handle array columns is using [higher-order functions](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/data-transformation/higher-order-lambda-functions.html).

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

output_df = (input_df
             .withColumn('list', f.expr('TRANSFORM(list, (element, i) -> STRUCT(ARRAY(COALESCE(list[i - 2], 0), COALESCE(list[i - 1], 0)) AS past, element AS future))'))
             .selectExpr('id', 'inline(list)'))

+---+------+------+
|id |past  |future|
+---+------+------+
|2  |[0, 0]|1     |
|2  |[0, 1]|2     |
|2  |[1, 2]|3     |
|2  |[2, 3]|4     |
|2  |[3, 4]|5     |
+---+------+------+
```

### UPDATE

Passing `N` dynamically before creating the expression:

```
N = 2

expr = 'TRANSFORM(list, (element, i) -> STRUCT(TRANSFORM(sequence({N}, 1), k -> COALESCE(list[i - k], 0)) AS past, element AS future))'.format(N=N)
output_df = (input_df
             .withColumn('list', f.expr(expr))
             .selectExpr('id', 'inline(list)'))
```

Comment: Hi! Is quite close to what im looking for, would there be any to make it able to change N? the window size to create the past column.

Comment: Yeah sure, its a very clean solution you came up with :) Thanks! Accepted answer now, will try tmw morning in a bigger dataset but should work.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, is there a way to extract the last row of each `id` into a different dataframe? For the example this would mean to have the row `2, [3,4], 5` into a different dataframe.

Comment: NVM! See https://pastebin.com/kFT5WmL3. I found a way with creating a new column with boolean value to store if its the final row or not and then i filter based on it. Im open for suggestions if you think it could be more optimal, first time using this first order functions! Seems neat!

Comment: You can use `last` function, it will retrieve your last id over specified window. After it, just apply a `where` to check if your `id` column has the same value as `last` id column

Comment: I recommend you to create another question, just to keep your original question and how to create a dataframe with only last id separated