# Pyspark explode multiple columns with sliding window

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a question similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68805893/pyspark-explode-array-column-into-sublist-with-sliding-window/68809510?noredirect=1#comment121607936_68809510)  but with the addition that extra columns need to be applied and I need to know what element was the last of the list where the sliding window was applied.

I'll give an example:

Given a df:

```
input_df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (2,[1,2,3,4,5], ["a","b","c","c","b"], ["a","a","c","c","d"]),
    ], ("id", "target", "feature1", "feature2"))

input_df.show():
+---+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| id|         target|       feature1|       feature2|
+---+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|  2|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|[a, b, c, c, b]|[a, a, c, c, d]|
+---+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

I would like to break each single line into multiple rows with a fixed size sliding window over the line. Resultant df would be like this:

```
output_df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (2, [1,2], 3, ["a","b"], ["a","a"], False), (2, [2,3], 4, ["b","c"], ["a","c"], False), (2, [3,4], 5, ["c","c"], ["c","c"], True),
    ], ("id", "past-target", "future-target", "past-feature1", "past-feature2", "islast"))

output_df.show():
+---+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------+
| id|past-target|future-target|past-feature1|past-feature2|islast|
+---+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------+
|  2|     [1, 2]|            3|       [a, b]|       [a, a]| false|
|  2|     [2, 3]|            4|       [b, c]|       [a, c]| false|
|  2|     [3, 4]|            5|       [c, c]|       [c, c]|  true|
+---+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------+
```

The logic should be to take columns `["target", "feature1", "feature2"]` and apply a sliding window of N(given as parameter, 2 in this case) where a pointer is put on the N element, creating a list for the past indexes of values in the column as `[past-target, past-feature1, past-feature2]` and the current value as `future-target`. Current value on the features columns can be ignored.

The first column of output df is created by looking at the first index after `N` (3rd, since n=2), use it as `future-target`. Then look at the 1st and 2nd value on the lists on `["target", "feature1", "feature2"]` to create values `[1,2], [a,b], [a,b]` of the `[past-target, past-feature1, past-feature2]`. Value of `islast` is set to False since the pointer is not the last element of `target`. This is done over and over to create the output_df

It's a hard logic to follow, and I don't really know how to do it with pyspark, happy to explain more if needed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I found an answer with support to also allow for padding (add extra values to the list if we want to have all values a possible future_target)

Code:

```py
filler_token = "-1"

main_feature = "target"
extra_features = ["feature1", "feature2"]
past_length = 2

expr = f'TRANSFORM({main_feature}, (element, i) -> STRUCT(TRANSFORM(sequence({past_length}, 1), k -> COALESCE({main_feature}[i - k], {filler_token})) AS pasts,' + \
       ''.join([f'TRANSFORM(sequence({past_length}, 1), k -> COALESCE({feature}[i - k], {filler_token})) AS past{feature}, ' for feature in extra_features]) + \
       f'element AS future, \
       i=SIZE({main_feature})-1 as final))'

output_df = (input_df
             .withColumn(features[0], f.expr(expr))
             .selectExpr('id', f'inline({features[0]})'))

padding=False
if(not padding):
  output_df = output_df.filter(~array_contains(col("pasts"), filler_token)) #filter out those with -1


output_df.show()

+---+------+-------------+-------------+------+-----+
| id| pasts|pastsfeature1|pastsfeature1|future|final|
+---+------+-------------+-------------+------+-----+
|  2|[1, 2]|       [a, b]|       [a, a]|     3|false|
|  2|[2, 3]|       [b, c]|       [a, c]|     4|false|
|  2|[3, 4]|       [c, c]|       [c, c]|     5| true|
+---+------+-------------+-------------+------+-----+

# If we put padding=True it will be like this
+---+--------+-------------+-------------+------+-----+
| id|   pasts|pastsfeature1|pastsfeature1|future|final|
+---+--------+-------------+-------------+------+-----+
|  2|[-1, -1]|     [-1, -1]|     [-1, -1]|     1|false|
|  2| [-1, 1]|      [-1, a]|      [-1, a]|     2|false|
|  2|  [1, 2]|       [a, b]|       [a, a]|     3|false|
|  2|  [2, 3]|       [b, c]|       [a, c]|     4|false|
|  2|  [3, 4]|       [c, c]|       [c, c]|     5| true|
+---+--------+-------------+-------------+------+-----+
```

I didnt go with udf as they were much slower than this solution.

Answer (score -1):

I think your best bet is using a UDF, just wrap all of your logic inside and you'll be fine. The only tricky part is you'd have to return an array of tuples, so you can explode them to multiple rows later. Check the demo code below.

```py
# Pure Python function here
def func(target, feature1, feature2, n=2):
    # implement your logic here
    # ...
    # this is just dummy return values
    return [
        ([1, 2], 3, ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'a'], False),
        ([2, 3], 4, ['b', 'c'], ['a', 'c'], False),
        ([3, 4], 5, ['c', 'c'], ['c', 'c'], True),
    ]

# ... which you can do simple unittest
func([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'b'], ['a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'd'])

# ... then use it as a UDF like this
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

schema = T.ArrayType(T.StructType([
    T.StructField('past_target', T.ArrayType(T.IntegerType())),
    T.StructField('future_target', T.IntegerType()),
    T.StructField('past_feature1', T.ArrayType(T.StringType())),
    T.StructField('past_feature2', T.ArrayType(T.StringType())),
    T.StructField('is_last', T.BooleanType()),
]))

(df
    .withColumn('temp', F.explode(F.udf(func, schema)('target', 'feature1', 'feature2', F.lit(2))))
    .select('id', 'temp.*')
    .show()
)

# Output
# +---+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------+
# | id|past_target|future_target|past_feature1|past_feature2|is_last|
# +---+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------+
# |  2|     [1, 2]|            3|       [a, b]|       [a, a]|  false|
# |  2|     [2, 3]|            4|       [b, c]|       [a, c]|  false|
# |  2|     [3, 4]|            5|       [c, c]|       [c, c]|   true|
# +---+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------+
```